# Backbone - How can I slice a collection?

Tags: backbone.js

I've got a Backbone Collection. How can I slice the collection, or at least truncate the list to a certain length?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that you have your collection defined and initialized and that you want to mutate the collection (change it in place) you have to do:

```
collection.reset(collection.first(n));
```

of you can use `.last(n)` to get last N elements.

If you just wanted to get the first n elements without modyfying the collection just do:

```
var models = collection.first(n);
```

Here is a [list of all the underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) you can use directly on your collection.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `first()` could take an argument. Thanks!